# Is this use of 'whom' correct?

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects

Apologies for the subject matter but, from a recent novel:

> This was a person I had known for several years, since college, **whom** I had seen vomit, whose life-changing cover letter I had basically rewritten.

I'm confused about subject/object here. The usual rule is to invert the sentence. "I had seen **him** vomit" argues for "whom" but I'm not sure it applies in this case.

Comment: Yes, _whom_ is the right word there. And your logic is right as well.

Comment: You might be confused because, "...***who** I had seen vomit, ...*" is also correct, and more common, at least in North America. With "whom" sounds formal or old-fashioned.